# Show that $(R^{\times}, \cdot)$ form a group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Isn't it sufficient to give the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)#Group_of_units) of a *group of units*

> The units of a ring $R$ form a group under multiplication, the group of units of $R$.

to show that $R^{\times}$ form a group under multiplication ?

If not, is it okay to present the neutral element, the inverse element and that the multiplication leads to closure by writing:

Since $(R, +, \cdot)$ is a commutative Ring with $1$, there exists an element $1$ in $R$ with $a \cdot 1 = a $ for all $a \in R^{\times}$. There also exists for each $a \in R^{\times}$ an inverse element $a^{-1}$ so that $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$. 
Let $a, b \in R^{\times}$ then $(a \cdot b)(a \cdot b)^{-1} = a \cdot b \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b^{-1} = a \cdot a^{-1} \cdot b \cdot b^{-1} = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 \Rightarrow a\cdot b \in R^{\times} \quad\forall a,b \in R^{\times} $

Comment: If you have this result at your disposal, it's fine.

Comment: $R$ should have a $1$, and you need to prove that the product of two units is again a unit.  After that, it is automatic.

Comment: @Randall _Technically_, you also need to prove that the inverse of a unit is a unit, but that's close to a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you've cited is not a definition. It's *a theorem followed by a definition*. You are asked to prove the theorem contained in that statement.

For instance, here's my definition of the group of primes:

> (Theorem) The irreducible natural numbers form a group under multiplication. (Definition) We call that group $\widehat{\Bbb N}$, the *group of primes*.

It is rather apparent that the first sentence is false, and therefore the subsequent definition is moot - or, at the very least, it can't hold as it is supposed to.

For the task at hand, you need to prove that:

- the restriction of the multiplication to $R^\times \times R^\times$ has image contained in $R^\times$ (important)
- that $R^\times$ contains an element $u$ such that $u x=x u=x$ for all $x\in R^\times$ (what might it be?)
- the multiplication is associative (easy)
- for all $x\in R^\times$, there is $y\in R^\times$ such that $yx=xy=u$ (what might it be?).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've updated the question.